# how to store appointment using solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-design, remix

I am making  an appointment system using Ethereum network where users can book appointments and service providers can approve these appointments. My question is how can i show users the schedule of a particular service provider.
here is a view of appoinment contract.

```
//pragma solidity ^0.4.23;
contract Appointment{
  enum AppointStatus {
    CREATED,
    CONFIRMED,
    IN_SESSION,
    COMPLETED,
    CANCELLED
  }

address public owner;
uint public id;
string public title;
AppointStatus public status;
uint public timeNow;
uint public timeBookedFor;

constructor(
uint _id,
string _title,
uint _timeNow,
uint _timeBookedFor
) 
public {
    owner = msg.sender; 
    id = _id;
    title = _title;
    doctor = _doctor;
    timeNow = _timeNow;
    status = AppointStatus.CREATED;
    timeBookedFor = _timeBookedFor;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can a separate contract which has all the listings of the schedules of the Service Providers

Your Appointment Contract must inherit this contract and have a function that calls the Parent function for getting all the schedules and once this function returns something  you can fire and event and show all the listings of the schedule.

Simplifying it:

contract ServiceProviders{

write a function that lists all the services and schedule provided for that 
  particular service Provider and return the result to anyone who calls this 
  function

}

Now inherit above contract to your Appointment contract

contract Appointment is ServiceProviders {

Here you must write a function getServices() which calls ServiceProviders 
  Contract function and returns the entire list

Once the list is returned, You can fire an event within this function to 
  whoever calling this function and show them the listings.

}

Hope it helps!